# C - Writing to File Example from Textbook not writing to file

Tags: c

I am using C++ Compiler to program in C (Instructor Requirement).

I am reading my C textbook and copied down their first example program to write to a file, and compiled it. When I run it (and write some things in as shown in book), nothing is written to the file.

```
int main(void) {
int account;
char name[30];
double balance;

FILE *cfPtr;

if ((cfPtr = fopen("clients.txt", "w")) == NULL) {
    printf("File could not be opened\n");

}
else {
    printf("Enter the account, name, and balance.\n");
    printf("Enter EOF to end input.\n");
    printf("? ");
    scanf("%d%s%lf", &account, name, &balance);

    while (!feof(stdin)) {
        fprintf(cfPtr, "%d %s %.2f\n", account, name, balance);
        printf("? ");
        scanf("%d%s%lf", &account, name, &balance);
    }
    fclose(cfPtr);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots if not necessary (which is obviously the case here...).

Comment: Are you sure you wanna send `^Z` and not `^D`?

Comment: How do you get "out of the while loop"? Do you kill the program? If so, then you fclose(cPtr) is not executed. It needs to be executed to store the data into the file.

Comment: @kebs Okay, I removed it.

Comment: @Siguza Ctrl Z does nothing and Ctrl D sent in to some infinite loop of question marks that wrote the last thing over and over and over to the file

Comment: @tangoal EOF is supposed to end it. Books has it as CTRL Z

Comment: What OS are you using? If it's Windows I don't think Ctrl+D is EOF.

Comment: regarding: `while (!feof(stdin)) {`  The function: `feof()` does not do what you are expecting.  Suggest using; `while( scanf("%d%s%lf", &account, name, &balance) ==3 )`  to control the loop iterations

Comment: regarding: `printf("File could not be opened\n")`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  When the error is from a system function, like `fopen()`, then the check for success (and the function has failed) should be followed by: perror( "fopen failed" ); cleanup then call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`   The call to `perror()` will output the enclosed text AND the text reason the system thinks the function failed.

Comment: the value EOF is not something entered from the keyboard.  Rather, just click 'enter', all by it self.   This action will cause the call to `scanf()` to fail, which will get the code out of the loop.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions,  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) the input format specifiers: `%s` and `%[...]` can easily overrun the input buffer, resulting in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.  Always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer, because those two input specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace  '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: The posted code does not compile!  It is missing the necessary `#include` statements for the needed header file(s)`  When asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and assist in debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code it works perfectly.
I think you may be using windows compiler.
So you should use ctrl-z as the EOF.
If you are a Linux user..then use ctrl-z to give EOF..
But if you use ctrl-c or any other interupt keys , then your data's won't be written in the file , because it is kept in the buffer when you close the FILE pointer only then buffers are written to the file .

Comment: If Linux user use ctrl-d ...sorry auto-correction is enabled in my keyboard ...so it went wrong